# Hosting an example WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, url, ftp

I applied for a role and part of the application process requires me to build a WordPress site and make it live on a existing domain I own. This will assist the hiring company (example "WebCompany") to view and assess.

I have created the WordPress site locally and want to upload to my domain (e.g. www.mydomain.com.au) with a url extension like www.mydomain.com.au/webcompany.

Would it be as simple as just FTP the WordPress site to the root directory? Or do I need to set things up differently for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install wordpress on your url with the same version, and use this plugin, I use it and helps even if you have info in your database, and your themes, all the stuff,
and then you have to active the plugins on the web, choose permalinks options.

[WORDPRESS ALL-IN ONE PLUGIN](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

1. for the extension / what you mean really? you want wordpress on a /namefolder

because you can install wordpress in a folder and there's your extension, but if you have already wordpress installed on the public_html/ you can use multisite wordpress options.

Here is the info and I did it with this:

[MultiSite Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)